# Which conditional statement is more pythonic?

Tags: python

Which of the following would you consider more Pythonic:

`return x if not x > 5 or not variable == True else y`

or

`return x if not (x > 5 and variable == True) else y`

Comment: `variable == True` is not Pythonic. You should just use `variable` or, if you really need to see if it *is the boolean object `True`*, then do `variable is True`.

Comment: Why somebody think that Pythonic is opinion-based?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this as

```
return y if x > 5 and variable else x
```

The fact that you negate your conditional in the second option makes it easy to switch the `if` and `else` parts of this statement.

Also, it is (almost) never a good practice in any language to compare a boolean value to true as in

```
if variable == True:
```

Just write

```
if variable:
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither is more Pythonic, it's just a question of how you structure your boolean logic. I would, however, replace `variable == True` with simply `variable`.